# Lock a sheet then export URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Absolute noobie here, just trying to automate a process we currently do manually between google sheets.

I'd like to have a script attached to a button that does the following when pressed -

- "lock" a vlookup or freeze a cell's contents. (I use a separate sheet of prices for materials that changes over time. When a quote gets accepted, I want to be able to "lock" the data that's already been pulled across from the other sheet, so the customer only pays what they've been quoted.
- export the current sheet URL (or ID) to another sheet. I've got a "dashboard" sheet that we use as an overview of all the other sheets. Once the button is pressed I want to add the current sheet to the list of sheets we are monitoring on the dashboard sheet. Essentially I want to be able to extract the url of the sheet where we've just pressed the button, and add that url (or ID) to a list on another sheet.

Hope that makes sense! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use a sidebar often in the situation you end up wanting a lot more than just a button with a side bar it’s easy to update the user interface to a more complex user interface

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. The copyUrl function will paste the url to the first empty row in column B, you can change the column by changing the 2 on codeline 12.

```
function freeze(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.getDataRange().copyTo(activeSheet.getDataRange(),{contentsOnly:true});
}

function copyUrl(){
  const targetSheetId = 'xxxxxx';
  const targetSheetName = 'sheetname';
  const currentUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  const target = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSheetId).getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1,2).setValue(currentUrl);
}
```

#### References

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)